# error during input validation with log4j2 dependecy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i was wonder how to change to debug so that i can get the stacktrace,

i have tried various properties to get it but none of them is working.
the project is a sample restcontroller that takes usersid as input and logs it in the console.
i have dockerized this appilcation.
i want to know what java version and other versions so that i can learn about the logging cve's

Also i have another issue with this docker file

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-8-slim







WORKDIR /app


COPY src /app
COPY mvnw /app
COPY pom.xml /app
COPY mvnw.cmd /app
RUN mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage

WORKDIR /app/target
EXPOSE 8080 
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/log4jexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

i am getting build error in this particular case.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-02T11:06:47Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:repackage (repackage) on project log4jexample: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: "*`logging.level.=DEBUG`*" - The trailing `.` before the `=` seems wrong.

Comment: anyone here to sort this out?

Comment: "*Also i have another issue with this docker file ...*" - Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-8-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY src /app/src
COPY pom.xml /app
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package

WORKDIR /app/target
EXPOSE 8080 
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/target/log4jexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

This docker file resolved my build failure issue after some trial and error.